# C++ Google-Style: Automatic correction

Tags: c++, checkstyle

I have a research project with several files (~100).
The code has been written over the years without any specific style. Each developer (mostly master students that come, code and leave) used their own "style", if any.

Now, I'm trying to maintain the code in a way to make new people that join us follow certain rules. I found that Google published some [style-guide](https://code.google.com/p/google-styleguide/). Luckily enough they published also a python script, that is easy to use.

**The problem** is, the script gives me for each file a tone of *silly* errors like

```
Missing space after ,  [whitespace/comma] [3]
```

or

```
Missing space before {  [whitespace/braces] [5]
```

**My question** is: Is it somehow possible to automatize the correction of such "errors"? That mean running a script over a file that  eliminates automatically all those errors.

Comment: astyle is a pretty decent tool for this, though it can't comply with the google-style 100%, it can get pretty darn close

Comment: I had downloaded eclipse-cpp-google-style.xml and notified Eclipse and that was all!

Comment: Why don't you use tools such as AStyle or GNU indent?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`clang-format`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) might be useful, as it can be run with an option to use Google style rules:

```
clang-format -style=Google ...
```

See e.g. http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

Comment: And of course, contrary to more rudimentary formatting tools clang-format understand C++ as clang's itself does.

Comment: Excellent tool, you may also install a plugin for Eclipse - https://github.com/wangzw/CppStyle to do it automatically for all your projects, it actually does it when you save it too.

Answer (score 1):

To update this answer for those of you using `vscode`, there's an extension there called [`clang-format`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xaver.clang-format) and in the settings there is the parameter

```
Clang-format › Language › Cpp: Style
clang-format fallback style for C++, left empty to use clang-format.style
```

Typing `google` in the text box should enable application of the Google formatting rules.